# Copy a WHOLE Typo3 Website to new domain (and upgrade from 4.5 to 6.2)

Tags: dns, migration, typo3, typo3-6.2.x, typo3-4.5

I am trying to copy a whole website with all its contents, configurations, settings, etc. to a new domain. The website's Typo3 version at the moment is **4.5.x**. Once I've copied it over I want to upgrade the version to **6.2.x**.

I know this is quite broad, but I really need some help on this so I can get this done by the end of the year.

Any help? :)

Answer (score 0):

Just copy all files and make dump of whole database to make copy.

DO NOT forget change credentials of the database connection otherwise you may accidentally change data of old domain being at new one.

probably you'll need also change domain specific configs... but that depends on the page.

For updating just check instructions in TYPO3 docs... there's no any singl answer it can be easy just like updating all extensions, all it may be impossible, cause extenasions methods may be depreciated/removed in 6.2...

Comment: Thanks! I managed to copy all the files, but I'm not quite sure how I should get a copy of the database... I am using phpMyAdmin and I think exporting the database then importing it to the new phpMyAdmin would be right...? (do I have to change anything if I have PHP 5.2 on the old and PHP 5.4?)

Comment: Yes, using phpMyAdmin is most common way, make sure that your new database has set proper charset for databases by default (it's utf-8 for TYPO3 ver. 6+ you'll need to convert charset of all tables and fields if old DB isn't utf-8)